# Load content from external file to div - Javascript tags not loading as expected

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to load content from another file in the div with with `id="display"`. I attempted to do this using Javascript, and it does work (changes the content of the div), although there are some issues with it. It loads everything from the desired file except the `<script>` tag (I used it because it doesn't load it with the `src` attribute either). If I click the button with the `onclick` function (I also used it for practical purposes), it says it's not defined.

I have tried everything I can think of, and have not yet found an acceptable solution.

HTML:

```html
<div class="btn_disp_container">
  <button class="btn_disp" value="servicios-propiedades-php">Inscripción de      propiedades</button>
  <button class="btn_disp" value="servicios-comercio-php">Inscripción de comercio</button>
  <button class="btn_disp" value="servicios-civiles-php">Inscripción de Soc. Civiles</button>
  <button class="btn_disp" value="servicios-otros-php">Otros Servicios</button>
</div>
<div class="display_container">
  <div id="transition" class="transition" data-visible="false">
    <!-- Transition of the content -->
  </div> 
  <div id="display">
    <!-- Display all of the content -->
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```js
const btn_display = document.querySelectorAll('.btn_disp');

for (const btn of btn_display) {
  btn.addEventListener('click', displayHtml);
}

function displayHtml() { // Loading information to the display
  const transition = document.getElementById('transition');
  const visible = transition.getAttribute('data-visible');

  if (visible === 'false') { // Verify that the transition is not activated
    transition.setAttribute('data-visible', true);
    const btn = this;

    const [folder, file, type] = this.getAttribute('value').split('-');

    let route;
    if (type === undefined) {
      route = `/RPPyC/pages/disp/${folder}/${file}.html`;
    } else {
      route = `/RPPyC/pages/disp/${folder}/${file}.${type}`;
    }

    const display = document.getElementById('display');

    transition.classList.add('transition-moving');
    enableButton(btn);

    checkRoute(route)
      .then(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          enableBack(display);
          let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
              display.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
            }
          };
          xhr.open('GET', route, true);
          xhr.send();

        }, 1500);
      })
      .catch(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          enableBack(display);
          display.innerHTML = '<div class="nosotros_info_cont2"><p>¡Surgió un problema con la ruta! Verifica que coincida el valor del botón con la ruta del archivo (Carpeta-Archivo)</p></div>'
        }, 1500);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          transition.classList.remove('transition-moving');
          transition.setAttribute('data-visible', false);
        }, 3000)
      });
  } else {}
}

function checkRoute(route) { // Check if the file exists
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        if (xhr.status == 200) {
          resolve();
        } else {
          reject();
        }
      }
    };
    xhr.open('HEAD', route, true);
    xhr.send();
  });
}

function enableBack(display) {
  display.classList.add('display-active');
}

function enableButton(btn) {
  for (const btn of btn_display) {
    btn.classList.remove('btn_disp-active');
  }
  btn.classList.add('btn_disp-active');
}
```

This is the file that is being loaded:

```
<div class='servicios_info_cont'>
    <div class='servicios_text_cont'>
        <h1>Inscripción de propiedades</h1>
        <h5>Requisitos:</h5>
        <p>1 . Presentar Escritura Pública</p>
        <p>2 . Certificado de Libertad de Gravamen</p>
        <p>3 . Certificado de valor Fiscal o Catastral (vigencia de 90 días)</p>
        <p>4 . Certificado de solvencia de impuesto predial (vigencia de 90 días)</p>
        <p>5 . Certificado de solvencia de Agua Potable</p>
        <p>6 . Comprobante Domiciliario Catastral (CDC)</p>
        <p>7 . Aviso de translado de dominio e ISABI</p>
        <p>8 . ISR (en caso de que cause)</p>
        <p>9 . Pago de derecho de inscripción a inmuebles</p>
        <p>10 . Pago de derecho de fojas de Testimonio</p>
    </div>
    <div class='servicios_table_cont'>
        <div class='servicios_calc_header'>
            <p id='calc_title' class='servicios_calc_title' onclick='saludo()'>Calcular pago de derechos de fojas de Testimonio</p>
            <div class='servicios_calc_container'>
                <div class='servicios_calc'>
                    <p>Introduce la cantidad de fojas</p>
                    <input type="text" placeholder='Solo números'>
                    <button>Calcular</button>
                </div>
                <div class='servicios_calc_total'>
                    <p>Costo: <span>$67.09<span></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        function saludo(){
        console.log('Hola');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Well, because that's how it works.  All you are doing here is assigning a string to `innerHtml`.  The new tags are added to the DOM, but no Javascript will be executed.

Comment: An [HTML iframe element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) might be what you're looking for

Comment: With the right code, you can load and execute scripts successfully - having said that, the script you've shown wouldn't run since `DOMContentLoaded` won't trigger, and that script basically creates a function that never runs and can't be accessed outside of the scope it was created in, so even if DOMContentLoaded triggered, it would be pointless

Comment: oh that accepted answer insists on using eval ... how old is it

Comment: here's something I wrote a few years ago (I modernised it now though) - https://jsfiddle.net/1uvhakrn/ - it does similar things to a few of those years old answers, but in a more modern way, and I added the "SUBContentLoaded" event you can use inside any "imported" scripts to use instead of "DOMContentLoaded" which of course only ever triggers once